# How to grouping lines to a block?

Tags: vba, autocad

I want to create a square with autocad and grouping them to a block.

```
Call CreateLine(p1, p2) 'creating top line
Call CreateLine(p2, p3) 'creating right line 
Call CreateLine(p3, p4) 'creating bottom line
Call CreateLine(p4, p1) 'creating left line

Function CreateLine(firstPoint, secondPoint)
    Dim StartPoint(0 To 2) As Double
    Dim EndPoint(0 To 2) As Double
    StartPoint(0) = firstPoint(0)
    StartPoint(1) = firstPoint(1)
    StartPoint(2) = 0
    
    EndPoint(0) = secondPoint(0)
    EndPoint(1) = secondPoint(1)
    EndPoint(2) = 0
    
    With ThisDrawing.ModelSpace
    .AddLine StartPoint, EndPoint
    .Item(.Count - 1).Update
    End With
     
    
End Function
```

now I want grouping this square to a block with a custom name with `VBA` and AutoCAD.
How can I do?

Comment: groupObject.AppendItems (Item) ?

Answer (score 0):

If You want to join them as block You should draw inside the block - not in `ModelSpace`. Then insert the block reference.

Like this:

```
Dim p0(0 To 2) As Double
p0(0) = 0
p0(1) = 0
p0(2) = 0

Dim block As AcadBlock
Set block = ThisDrawing.Blocks.Add(p0, "*")

Dim line As AcadLine
Set line = block.AddLine(firstPoint, secondPoint)

Dim ref As AcadBlockReference
Set ref = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(p0, block.Name, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: why u use p0 to insert block?

Comment: Any block reference must be inserted at some point so I used origin. In Your post, You use the words `group` and `block` which are very different. When You use the group - if You select one entity, each other will be chosen. If You copy one, you'll copy all. But the block is the definition of a complex entity. So You may define it once and insert it many times, where each line will not be copied. if You edit in one reference each will be changed. So the construction of the block forces me to use a point, like the construction of a circle force to specify the center point.

Comment: In my example variable `block` is just block definition that is never inserted yet - is not visible on the model space, and may never be. May be used in other blocks or the paper space.